# Teradata POSITION with occurrence

Tags: sql, teradata

In MySQL DB, this is the query:

```
SELECT LOCATE(BINARY 'st','myteststring',6); 
output: 7
```

In Teradata, how can I achieve the same?

Comment: Doesn't Teradata have a manual where this is documented?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSTR('myteststring','st',6)
```

If the *position* is negative it searches backwards starting at the end of the string.

And there's a 4th parameter, to return the ***n***th occurence of a string.

Comment: @VivekHarry: Yep, `string` and `searchstring` are swapped.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT LOCATE(BINARY 'st','myteststring',6);

from the above query you are getting result as 7 which is the position of second occurrence of 'st'.

In teradata you can use below query to get your desired result:-

select INSTR('MYTESTSTRING','ST',1,2);

*** Query completed. One row found. One column returned. 
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

### INSTR('MYTESTSTRING','ST',1,2)

```
                                   7
```

INSTR(STRING,SERARCH_STRING,STARTING POSITION,OCCURANCE)